# Viewer throwing wgs.js not found error

Tags: autodesk-viewer

This morning when I went to access the viewer, I got the following error:

[image: WGS.js missing error]

I assume I just need to add a script reference for this file, but i can't see any documentation telling me when to download it from.

If I use version 2.12 of the viewer then I have no issues.

For anyone else with this error, just update your script tag for the viewer3D.js to be the following:

```
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.js?v=2.12.*"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check all the public version of viewer, you can check the link https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers, all the minor versions are listed. And Yes, the latest version should be already 2.13.*.

But, as you noticed, 2.10 is still the default version, this is because of some internal reason, sorry if this brings any confusion.

If you want to check the change log for all these recent versions of viewer, the public link is https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/changelog/. But for the latest version, sometime it may not be included there, you can pay attention to our new Forge blog system, for example, the blog https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v213 listed the new improvement of viewer 2.13.

Answer (score 0):

The viewer default version has been changed back to version 2.10. Which seems to be a much more stable version.

Can anyone from Autodesk please advice how we find out about the versioning and releases? How do we know what is in each minor version?

The website only seems to show information for version 2, not any of the minor releases.

Answer (score 0):

The Forge team makes these announcements on 'Autodesk Forge' blog site, for each minor version released.  Go to the Forge developer site -> blog, and search for the keyword 'release' (click either of the links below to get there)

Here are links to the release notes for versions 2.14 & 2.15:

version 2.14: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v214-0

version 2.15: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v215